# What does Field in Redux-Form do with the prop `input`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

In the below component I don't get what is the point of spreading `{...input}`. What is the `input` prop? It doesn't appear to be passed in by the container form in the [example](http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/syncValidation/), so it must be from the Redux-form library. But what is it exactly?

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (

  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
      {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: redux form uses the field component to pass additional props. The input would be the props specified on your input. so like type="text" name=""... etc. if you are really curious what it is why not debug and inspect its value or `console.log(input)` before you return the jsx

Comment: I can see they are functions and in the docs they can set off callbacks when the events occur, so I tried adding `{input.onFocus(console.log('blur'))}` before the `touch &&..` code above but it console.logs blur twice instead of once when I focus. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I'd have to see code to know what you are trying to describe. Did you try doing `console.log(input)` ? And why are you trying to put a focus on the javascript variable? you have a jsx input being rendered right there.. why not put the events on it?

Comment: you shouldn't be creating callback events in your render. thats probably why you see it twice (because a render happens on blur). You also will be creating this listener for every render. really bad idea

Comment: can you give me an example of when you would use an input prop? I get how meta props are used, but not input props. Seems like the value one just makes the input element a controlled component, but how would you customize what happens on blur?

Comment: what version of redux form?

Comment: just look at their docs... http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/docs/api/Field.md/#props . ... when you pass props to a `Field` they are extended onto an input variable that stores everything you want on your element. ex. `<Field onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="email" component={renderField} />` inside the `renderField` function the items inside the `input` parameter should be the ones passed to the `Field` aka onChange, type, name. These you want to extend onto the input. Its making the component a controlled component

Comment: I understand how it gets passed to the input, but the docs don't give an example of how these input props are used specifically.

Comment: Yes they do, you spread them out on a html input element so you have inputs that have different attributes for every Field